# Is an "Aura" a "spell"that is cast? Such as the new Barbarian subclass Path of Storm.

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

So basically I'm trying to figure out if Elemental Adept would work in conjunction with the new Path of the Storm Herald's "Sea" (which is lightning) damage.

Answer (score 11):

### It's not a spell, it's a class feature like Rage and Wild Shape.

Spells have casting time, components, range, target, etc. The Storm Aura from the Path of the Storm Herald is a class feature for the new Barbarian archetype.

Comment: I edited this (good) answer to use the phrase "class feature" rather than "ability", since that's the specific rules term used to classify these types of abilities.

Comment: @Marq : You left "ability" in the main body.

Comment: Do you mean Rage rather than Fury in class feature, or is that an XGtE thing?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about my bad translation, I meant rage.

Comment: A niggle but it would make the answer better if you quoted the rule that shows why it not being a spell but being a class ability makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not a spell.

The simple way to tell: if it's listed in a spell list, it's a spell. They'll be written in a standard format, listing the spell level, components, casting time etc. That includes any class ability that says "you can cast *some spell*", where *some spell* is the name of an entry in the spell list - and yes, it will be written in *italics*. The only way for something to be a spell and not be on the spell list is if it says in its description that it is considered a spell. This is not the case with the Storm Herald's aura, and it's not listed in a spell list anywhere, it doesn't have a spell level, and it doesn't mention components. Therefore, it's not a spell.

Comment: I might have added "consumes a slot" to the list of things that make something a spell. (There are exceptions, like cantrips, but the general rule on PHB201 is that spells consume slots.)

Comment: @nitsua60 The general rule is that spells consume slots, but there are enough exceptions to this that I wouldn't use it as a hard rule. For example, a paladin's Divine Smite consumes a spell slot, but isn't a spell, and many warlock Invocations are spells, but don't consume spell slots. As far as I can see, the wording "you cast *italicised spell name*" and the presence of that name in a spell list chapter are the most consistent ways to spot a spell.

Comment: Fair points. +1 in any case =)